# How to change object display depending on type?

Tags: oop

I though I was ok with POO, but right now I'm all confused with the following.

---

### Basic model

For instance, let's say you've created `Dog` and `Cat` objects that extends the abstract class `Animal`.

`abstract Animal` has the generic properties:

- color: string
- legs: number

`Cat extends Animal` has the extra property:

- humansTolerance: number

`Dog extends Animal` has the extra property:

- ballsRetrieved: number

---

### Problem

Now, I want to display a list of all the animals on my application in a generic way. Simple, the application just pulls all the Animal objects from the database, puts them in a nice `List<Animal>` with each object instantiated with its proper class.

But now, when I click on one given animal, I want to be able to display the `Animal` generic properties AND the properties that are specific to its type.

For example, If the selected animal is a cat, I want the UI to show the generic animal properties `color` and `legs`, but I also want to display the cat property `humansTolerance`. Same goes for the dog with `ballsRetrieved`.

---

### Question

Am I supposed to use the often called infamous `instanceof` / `typeof` to do that? How can I make the UI display various elements depending on the type of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a virtual method or the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Ok this looks to be the good answer and that would work in Java.
The problem is that this pattern relies on method overloading and I'm working with Typescript.

Comment: Maybe I need to target the Angular community instead.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat What's the difference? Patterns are language agostic usually. E.g. here: https://github.com/gztchan/design-patterns-in-typescript/blob/master/visitor/visitor.ts

Comment: Ok I was wrong when I said it relied on overloading, I now understand the pattern better. I'm trying this. Thanks.

Comment: Using the visitor pattern worked fine but it adds a LOT of complexity to the application. I hope I'll find another way...

Answer (score 0):

The obvious object-oriented approach would be to just have a `display()` method in the objects. Each "class" displays itself:

```js
class Dog {
    ...
    public display(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't know what is "customary" in TypeScript, but the object-oriented approach would hide properties, and offer behavior instead.

Comment: Yeah but display in web applications is made with properties binding like in JSF with `${object.prop}` or in Angular with `{{object.prop}}`. But then again, maybe my question is more about the particular web case than POO. I need to dig more.